# Socket.io live chat - managing user friends

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

I am developing a live chat app in React / Redux, Node (Express), Socket.io and MySql. What I am trying to do is a live chat with no "public" room. It works on friendships / relations between users (a user that is friend with another can chat one to one) and also handles groups creation (a user can create a group with as many other users he wants).

Everything is working fine, the only problem is that I am unsure of the best way to manage to get the friends / groups list (also showing online / offline status) of each user.

The way I did it for the moment is like the following :

- Every connected user is stored in an object in the backend (with their socket ID). Each key is the connected user ID and the value is its socket ID. It looks like this :

```
let connectedUsers = {
    1: 'socketIdUser1'
    2: 'socketIdUser2',
    5: 'socketIdUser5',
    // ... And so on for every user that is connected
}
```

If we are taking the above object as an example, we know that the users whose IDs are 1, 2 and 5 are connected.

- Then, for each individual connected user, I store their friendship relations with the others in another objet, looking like this (I only store the IDs) :

```
let userFriendsObject = {
    1: {
        2: 2,
        4: 4,
        5: 5,
    },
    2: {
        1: 1,
        5: 5,
        9: 9,
        12: 12,
    }
}
```

This object shows us that the user whose ID is 1 has a friendship (and therefore can chat with them) with the users whose IDs are 2, 4 and 5. While user with ID = 2 is friend with the users whose IDs are 1, 5, 9 and 12.

I keep track of every friendships like so to be able to send the correct friend list for each user. I found this method the most convenient at the moment, because in case of an update (let's say a user adds a friend or someone logs in and I have to send the user his correct updated friend list), it would be a pain to send the correct friend list to the correct user. Or maybe I am missing something ?

The code for when a user connects and get his friend list send from the backend to frontend looks like this :

- Frontend :

```
useEffect(() => {

    /* When a user connects, this event is emited to the backend, which 
    will then emit back the below "set user friends list" event */

    socket.emit('new connected user', { id: currentUser.id, pseudo: currentUser.pseudo });


    // Listening emited event from the backend, holding the user's friend list

    socket.on('set user friends list', friendStack => {
        if (friendStack) {
            // dispatch hook to set the friend list in Redux global state
            dispatch(setFriendList(friendStack)); 
        }   
    });

    
    // Listening emited event from the backend, updates online status for newly connected user's friends

    socket.on('set friend status', ({ friendId, isActive }) => {
        dispatch(setOnline({ id: friendId, changes: { isActive } }));
    });

}, []);
```

- Backend :

```
// "Global" object containing every connected user (key = user ID, value = socket ID)

let connectedUsers = {};

// "Global" object containing every user ID, themselves containing every friends IDs (= holding every friendships)

let userFriendsObject = {};

socket.on('new connected user', ({ userId, pseudo => {
    session.user = {
        id: userId,
        pseudo: pseudo,
        isActive: true,
    };
            

    connectedUsers[userId] = socket.id; // Used to know which users are connected
            
    session.save();


    /* I use EventEmitter() from the 'events' library to emit events 
    from the backend to the backend for everything DB related,
    to better split the code */ 
    
    eventEmitter.emit('get friends list', { userId });
            

    /* Function triggered below (after all the "sockets.on()",
    in eventEmitter.on('get friends list'), to process the 
    friend list received from the DB just above) */

    setFriendList = function(friends) {
        

         /* I emit to the newly connected user's socket his friend list */

         ioChat.to(socket.id).emit('set user friends list', friends[userId]);
                

        /* To update the online status ("isActive") of the friends side of the newly connected 
        user, I loop through connectedUser object keys (= connected users IDs) ... */

        for (let i in connectedUsers) {


            /* ... to compare it with the userFriendsObject key of the user to check
            (= his friend list), to know which of his friends are connected... */

            if (userFriendsObject[userId] && userFriendsObject[userId][i] === parseInt(i, 10) && parseInt(i, 10) !== userId) {

         
                /* ... and then send to his connected friends an event which will say 
                to them to update the status of the newly connected user */

                ioChat.to(connectedUsers[i]).emit('set friend status', { friendId: userId, isActive: true });
            }
        }
    };
});

// ...

eventEmitter.on('get friends list', async ({ userId }) => {
    try {
        // Setting the online status of the user in DB (1 = online, 0 = offline)

        await User.setUserStatus(userId, 1);


        // Calling the DB to get the user friends

        const friendList = await User.getUserFriendsData(userId);
        

        /* This variable will be "local" and hold all the user's friend list
        as a normalized object ready for Redux */
        
        let friends = {};

        
        // Loop through the friendList retrieved from the DB

        let i = 0, resultLength = friendList.length;
        for (i; i < resultLength; i++) {


            // Putting the "local" user's friend list in "friends" object   

            friends[userId] = {
                ...friends[userId],
                [friendList[i].userId]: {
                    id: friendList[i].userId,
                    pseudo: friendList[i].pseudo,
                    email: friendList[i].email,
                    createdOn: friendList[i].createdOn,
                    isActive: friendList[i].isActive !== 0,
                    roomId: friendList[i].roomId,
                }
            };


            /* Using userFriendsObject as a "global" object, holding every user's friend list
            (only the IDs though, as explained in the beginning of my post) */

            userFriendsObject[userId] = {
                ...userFriendsObject[userId],
                [friendList[i].userId]: friendList[i].userId,
            };
        }


            /* Here I call the setFriendList() function which is in 
            "socket.on('new connected user')" and is used 
            to process the friend list and emit events accordingly */

            setList(friends);
    }
    catch (error) { 
        console.error(`Error EE.on('get list') : ${error}`);
    }
});
```

I am sorry if this is not very clear, the code is pretty loaded. I tried my best to explain what is happening but please, feel free to tell me to elaborate if it is not clear (also, English is not my native language, making it even harden).

My concerns with this code are :

- 1. Is it OK to store every friendship relations for every user in a "global" object (userFriendsObject) ? I am concerned because if I have 100 connected users having 20 friends each, the object will be pretty big (min 2000 keys / values, nested 2 levels deep). Not to mention it should grow exponentially as the app is used.
- 2. What would be an alternative for not storing all these friendship relations in an object, but still be able to have every users friend list "at hand", in an effective and scalable alternative ?

In the following part of the code (setFriendList() function, in socket.on('new connected user') :

```
// Looping through the connectedUsers object...
for (let i in connectedUsers) {


    /* ... to compare it with the userFriendsObject key of the user to check
    (= his friend list), to know which of his friends are connected... */

    if (userFriendsObject[userId] && userFriendsObject[userId][i] === parseInt(i, 10) && parseInt(i, 10) !== userId) {

         
        /* ... and then send to his connected friends an event which will say 
        to them to update the status of the newly connected user */

        ioChat.to(connectedUsers[i]).emit('set friend status', { friendId: userId, isActive: true });
    }
}
```

- 3. Is it OK to emit to users (potentially a lot of them) in a loop like I have done ? If not, how can I make sure to send the correct updated friend list for a given user ? (I guess the answer is linked with my other questions).
- 4. Should I use some type of storage like indexedDB ?

I hope someone will be able to help me. My code works but I am pretty sure it is way far from optimal performances. Thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed it.

I did so by using Redis cache store.

What I do is, when I fetch every friends and groups for each user, I create a place in Redis store to store it. I can then get any users friends with the user ID.

```
const redis = require('redis');
const redisStore = redis.createClient();

// I can then store a friend (friend being a JSON object) like so :
redisStore.hset(`${userId}:friends`, friend.id, JSON.stringify(friend));

// This way I store every friend as a key / value in ${userId}:friends
// I can retrieve a specific friend by its ID like so :
redisStore.hget(`${userId}:friends`, friendID, (err, result) => {
    // Here, the stringified friend object with ID = friendID is in result variable
});

// Or I can get all friends of user = userId like so :
redisStore.hgetall(`${userId}:friends`, (err, results) => {
     // Here, every friends (stringified) of user with id = userId are in results variable
});
```

I justed started using Redis and I find it very powerful and perfect for the kind of application I use it for.

I don't need to use "global" objects anymore, like I did before to store the users friendship relations (like the "userFriendsObject" object). I can store anything I want in Redis and get it back quickly. It is also supposed to be incredibly quick as of performances.

I can also use any other storing data types or techniques depending on the situation.

I found a good place to start understanding Redis is there : https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro

And you can find every Redis commands here : https://redis.io/commands#